# Vector in a struct wont let me push_back

Tags: c++, vector, struct, pthreads

Hi i have a vector in a struct as follows for pthreads argument passing:

```
struct thread_data{
   vector< pair < Database, string> > list_databases;
   ...
   ...
};

...some more code...
```

then in a later function when i do the following
   ( mydata is a thread_data passed into the function )
   ( entry being a pair< Database, string > )

```
mydata->list_databases.push_back(entry);
```

whenever I do this it tells me that push_back is of non-class type. I dont understand the error. I also tried using:

```
vector< pair<Database,string> > * list_databases;
```

and

```
mydata->list_databases->push_back(entry);
```

and a combination of the two. All give me the same error. Can anyone suggest something? I've researched this and have been stuck on it for hours. Thank you

edit:

Here is the rest of the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

struct thread_data{
   vector< pair<Database, string> >* list_databases;
   const char* store;
}

void* load_store( void* threadarg );

int main (){
  vector< pair <Database, string> > list;
  pthread_t thread1;
  string test;
  cout <<"$ ";
  cin >> test;

  const char* store_name = test.c_str();

  struct thread_data tester;
  tester.store = store_name;
  tester.list_databases = &list;

  pthread_create(&thread1,NULL,load_store, (void*) &tester);
  return 0;
}

void * load_store( void* threadarg ){
  struct thread_data *mydata;
  mydata = (struct thread_data*) threadarg;
  string store_used = mydata->store;

  ifstream load;
  string conversion;
  Database Loader;
  load.open(store_used.c_str());

  if(!load){ cerr << "Does not exist" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  while(!load.eof()){
    //...pushes file contents into database Loader...
  }
  load.close();
  pair < Database, string > new_store(Loader, store);
  mydata->list_databases->push_back(new_store);     // this is where the error occurs
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the relevant declaration of code from the file that has `thread_data`, including `#includes`, `using` statements, etc.

Comment: i posted the rest of the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mydata->list_databases.push_back(entry);`, as you've shown in your question, will fail because `thread_data::list_databases` is a `vector<...>*` rather than a `vector<...>`. I.e., it's a pointer-type rather than a class-type, just as the compiler error you're seeing indicates.

`mydata->list_databases->push_back(new_store);`, as you've shown in your code sample, should work, except that you need to `#include <utility>` in order to use `std::pair`.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I completely forgot to add utility and about the pointer-type. I used so many combinations on my initial error i cant believe i missed this one. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a local variable in the `main` function, so it is destroyed when `main` returns (on the `return 0;` line in `main`).  You pass the address of this local variable to `load_store`, which you start on another thread.  If `load_store` tries to access `list` after `list` has been destroyed, bad things happen.

You need to synchronize access to `list`, probably by having `main` join with `thread1` before exiting.