# C++: vector in struct, push_back error

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I am trying to save the data in a vector in structs. Since I do not know the length of each data, I used `push_back`. However, the `for loop` does not work and I got `Command terminated` after the first `i` loop.

I tried several answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149880/vector-in-a-struct-wont-let-me-push-back), but none of them works.

Here is a simplified version of what I tried (and gives the same error):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    vector<int> words;
}DATA_STRUCT;

void add(DATA_STRUCT *data){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(int s=0;s<3; s++){
            (&data)[i] -> words.push_back(s);
            cout << i << s << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    DATA_STRUCT *data = new DATA_STRUCT[5];
    add(data);
    cout << (&data)[0] -> words[0] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.  Here is the correct approach :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef struct{
    vector<int> words;
}DATA_STRUCT;

void add(DATA_STRUCT *data){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        for(int s=0;s<3; s++){
            data[i].words.push_back(s);  //<-- edit
            cout << i << s << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    DATA_STRUCT *data = new DATA_STRUCT[5]; 
    add(data);
    cout << data[0].words[0] << endl;  //<-- edit
    delete[] data;                     //Thank juanchopanz
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://ideone.com/fi51rj)

`&data` is wrong, you want the value.
`data[xxx]` works like the "get value" operation. (roughly speaking)

### **Edit**

There is also memory leak at :-

```
DATA_STRUCT *data = new DATA_STRUCT[5];
```

It is **new** without **delete**, so I also add `delete[] data;`.  (Thank  *juanchopanza*)

### **Edit2**

To answer *Tom de Geus*:-

> Any way to avoid the new here?

Here is the better version :-

```
DATA_STRUCT data[5];
add(data);
cout << data[0].words[0] << endl;
```

**[Live demo](http://ideone.com/cRFvjH)**

### Edit2

To answer additional question from OP :-

> Why can we use arrow instead of dot? Is data in the add function a struct of pointer?

`data` is `DATA_STRUCT*`
`(&data)` is `DATA_STRUCT**`
`(&data)[i]` is `DATA_STRUCT*`
`(&data)[i]->` is `DATA_STRUCT`
`(&data)[i]->words` is `DATA_STRUCT::words`

It is a wrong address, but in term of (only) syntax, it is correct.
Wrong address ~ undefined behavior = can work OK / work but wrong / crash

Comment: Any way to avoid the `new` here? But I guess in this case clean up should still be automatic?

Comment: It is probably a good idea to mention the memory leak in the first sample and fix it, given that you're posting code.

Comment: @juanchopanza  Agree. I will fix it.

Comment: Great! I think that it is better to point these kind of issues out.

Comment: @javaLover Why can we use arrow instead of dot? Is data in the add function a struct of pointer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies with:

```
(&data)[i] -> words.push_back(s);
```

`&data` evaluates to a `DATA_STRUCT **data`. By using `(&data)[i]`, you are accessing memory that you are not supposed to, which causes undefined behavior.

That line can be a lot simpler.

```
data[i].words.push_back(s);
```

Comment: I am faster than the great R Sahu, Brwaaa!  This is my proud for today.

Comment: @javaLover, you are very kind :)